# Tool for generating 2d cartesian diagram

Tags: linux, ubuntu, data-visualization, graphs, diagram

I want to draw a 2D x-y Cartesian diagram from a bunch of points in (x, y) format and then connect some of them together. These coordination are already stored in a text file. I am looking for a simple and straightforward tool like [Graphviz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz) to plot them all in a 2D Cartesian diagram.

But unfortunately seems GraphViz does not support 2D Cartesian plotting. I would prefer a linux / ubuntu tool but Windows based tool is also OK.

For this: Can anyone suggest me an awesome tool for such purpose?

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need some more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked (which I did for you). You should always list your requirements explicitly (which you partly did already). Please take a look at [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details, and see if you can [edit] and improve your question – which will increase your chances for good answers. Thanks, and good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/)

I use Gnuplot for any kind of plotting. It is a cross-platform command line tool for plotting data in 2D and 3D diagrams. It is both fast (for quick visualization) and detailed (for professional reports).

An example of how to plot the (x,y) data you describe would be:

```
plot "<filename>" using 1:2 with lines
```

which could be abbreviated as `plot "<filename>" u 1:2 w l`. For more detailed plots and styles, you'll need to write script files, which are intuitive and easy to learn. [The documentation](http://www.gnuplot.info/documentation.html) is pretty detailed, and you could directly output your plots in many different formats, including Cairo PNG, TikZ, PostScript, and others.

Summary: Gnuplot is

- Cross-platform: runs on Linux and Windows
- Easy to learn and use: Simple commands that are mostly in natural language
- Plots 2D data from text files